# Android emulator sound - ubuntu

Tags: android, audio, android-emulator, alsa, qemu

Using Ubuntu 10.04 64 bits for Android development and everything goes well except sound.

I've using -audio option and -audio-out one with alsa as backend parameter, but without luck.

¿Any idea?

Comment: Did you find out how to solve this problem? I have stumble upon this too...

Comment: Still haven't found a solution.

Comment: Problem persists in `Ubuntu 16.10` 64-bit

Answer (score 3):

I'm setting up Android SDK on Ubuntu 10.04 64-bit and found the emulator segfaults on launch unless I specify "-no-audio" option.

This thread describes similar issues under Fedora:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/nL11no1Z87w

Both that thread, and one of the answers here suggest installing some extra ALSA / PulseAudio packages/libs.

However I found none of the ones mentioned appear to exist in the Ubuntu 10.04 repositories.

So for now I'm sticking with no-audio as an effective workaround allowing me to actually run the emulator. But then audio is not a priority for me...

Note an alternative of the command line "-no-audio" option is to tweak the Android Virtual Device in AVD manager and add "Audio Playback Support: no" and "Audio Recording Support: no" under "Hardware". With these changes I could then start the emulator from Eclipse and run my application in it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have 32bit sound packages installed if you are using a 64bit linux os, such as `libalsa-plugins` and `libalsa-plugins-pulseaudio` as well as their 64bit counterparts.

Comment: how to install them? there are no such packages in `apt` repository.

Answer (score -1):

android emulator does not ship alsa but uses a wrapper qemu sound module :

Hint: /dev/eac

-- 
http://rzr.online.fr/q/alsa